# Is member value in the class initialized when an object is created?

Tags: c++, initialization, member, c++03

I'm writing a hash class:

```
struct hashmap {
  void insert(const char* key, const char* value);
  char* search(const char* key);
 private:
  unsigned int hash(const char* s);
  hashnode* table_[SIZE]; // <--
};
```

As insert() need to check if table[i] is empty when inserting a new pair, so I need all pointers in the table set to NULL at start up.

My question is, will this pointer array `table_` be automatically initialized to zero, or I should manually use a loop to set the array to zero in the constructor?

Comment: `hashnode* table_[SIZE]{};`

Comment: I hope you're only doing this as an exercise, as C++ already has a hash-map in [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sadly no C++11 and boost in my project.

Comment: @chris why would it work?

Comment: @chris Can this guarantee that all pointers are set to zero?

Comment: @BЈовић, It's an in-class member value-initialization (or zero-initialization, I'm not exactly sure, but both work). A value-initialization for an array value-initializes each element, which is `nullptr` for pointers.

Comment: Oh, looks like value-initialization from [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=93152aa692ac4a0759295b959e8d318d-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad).

Comment: @chris Tried but looks like it is C++11 only :(

Comment: @Deqing, Yes, the answers work fine without, but that's the cleanest one imo.

Comment: @chris you can do that in the constructor (works for c++11), but not on the member variable

Comment: @BЈовић, [Are you sure?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=afa68afffe716c8d1abf6ae6508f7052-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad)

Comment: @chris LOL of course no. I just never saw that syntax. Thanks for putting it there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `table_` array will be *uninitialized* in your current design, just like if you say `int n;`. However, you can value-initialize the array (and thus zero-initialize each member) in the constructor:

```
struct hash_map
{
    hash_map()
    : table_()
    {
    }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: Tried `std::fill` but failed: `error: invalid conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘hashnode*’ [-fpermissive]`. Btw, no C++11 in my project :(

Comment: I was convinced this zero initialization worked in C++03 too. Are you saying it doesn't? I certainly use it in C++03 code, and gcc accepts it with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c++98`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Absolutely right, I don't know what I was thinking. I think I was thrown off by the fact that you can't initialize arrays with arbitrary content, but of course value-initialization works. Though it would be interesting to know whether this changed between C++98 and C++03!

Comment: @Deqing: Please see the updated version; this should work even in C++03. Sorry for being dense...

Comment: OK, thanks for checking it. That was scary! So there is no need for OP to play with `std::fill`, which is nice.

Comment: Beautiful! Just found that this is introduced in C++03. @juanchopanza I guess it is not working with C++98, though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set all pointers to NULL.
You do not have to use a loop, you can call in the contructor :

```
memset(table_, 0, SIZE*sizeof(hashnode*));
```