# In constructor, candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

This is the code:

```
class cat
{
    private:
        int height;
    public:
        cat (int inputHeight);
};

cat::cat (int inputHeight)
{
    height = inputHeight;
}

class twoCats
{
    private:
        cat firstCat;
        cat secondCat;
    public:
        twoCats (cat theFirstCat);
        void addSecondCat (cat theSecondCat);
};

twoCats::twoCats (cat theFirstCat)
{
    firstCat = theFirstCat;
}

void twoCats::addSecondCat (cat theSecondCat)
{
    secondCat = theSecondCat;
}

int main() {return 0;}
```

And these are the errors:

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘twoCats::twoCats(cat)’:
main.cpp:24:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘cat::cat()’
main.cpp:24:34: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:9:1: note: cat::cat(int)
main.cpp:9:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:1:7: note: cat::cat(const cat&)
main.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:24:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘cat::cat()’
main.cpp:24:34: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:9:1: note: cat::cat(int)
main.cpp:9:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:1:7: note: cat::cat(const cat&)
main.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I don't understand the following:

1. Why does the constructor for `twoCats` try to call the default constructor for `cat`? Surely it does not need to construct an instance of `cat` as when `twoCats` is initialised it will be passed an already initialised instance of `cat` which will have been passed the `int height` argument?
2. Why is the same block of error messages shown twice? I called `g++ main.cpp` on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: First of all, you don't initialize anything in your constructor. You assign to already initialized objects. Secondly, you only attempt to initialize `firstCat`. What else would `secondCat` use?

Comment: This has been answered zillions of times before.

Comment: @juanchopanza At least you have to admit the OP got the question format correct at 1st shot ;) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, and it is not that easy to find duplicates either.

Comment: There needs to be a better dup checker on here.  It's good to have different angles of looking at the same problem, but when the same problem and answer appears over and over....

Comment: @juanchopanza What do you think about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120162/is-member-value-in-the-class-initialized-when-an-object-is-created)? Not highly voted, but the answers well describe what's actually going on.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's much easier to find things through Google. Just include [`site:stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+"candidate+expects"+arguments+site%3Astackoverflow.com) in the search criteria and you can narrow it down to questions and answers on this site.

Comment: @thang That would be a tough job, it's even hard for the humans reviewers to find appropriate dupes on SO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, it's hard for human reviewers because human reviewers don't have as good a memory as the database.  bugzilla does dup checking relatively well.  when you enter a bug, it gives  a list of potential dups.  it doesn't need to say "hey, there's a dup".  It just needs to say "hey, it may be a dup.  have you checked out these questions?"

Comment: I have a feelin the OP is probably laughing and thinking "buncha nerds over analyzing my homework assignment"

Comment: What happens when you need three cats? Why not have a container of n cats?

Comment: @thang _"I have a feelin the OP is probably laughing and thinking "buncha nerds ..."_ LOL, that could well be. I could have just been  using my hammer just about an hour ago, to close this as a dupe. And as the OP just didn't  give any reaction, this should have been the right reaction, preventing others wasting their precious time here.

Comment: @thang No I was not thinking bunch of nerds, this wasn't my homework assignment, I was just playing with it, the help here has been really fantastic and useful

Comment: @NeilKirk Sorry I should have clarified, this was just some dummy code I whacked up quickly and had nothing to do with the original problem, I was just trying to create a MWE. Obviously the best solution for this situation is a vector of cats, I guess I should have come up with an example that made more sense :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a default constructor or initialize cat objects in `twoCats` constructor initilization list explicitly to avoid default construction.

> Why does the constructor for twoCats try to call the default
>   constructor for cat? Surely it does not need to construct an instance
>   of cat as when twoCats is initialised it will be passed an already
>   initialised instance of cat which will have been passed the int height
>   argument?

It needs to construct default values for `cat` objects

```
private:
    cat firstCat;
    cat secondCat;
```

in class `twoCats` because you didn't initialize them. In your constructor

```
cat::cat (int inputHeight)
{
    height = inputHeight;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}   // this is assignment
```

this is assignment to already created objects.

The rule is as follows: if you don't initialize instances explicitly in `ctor` initialization list then

1. Default `ctor` is called
2. You eventually assign to already default constructed objects in `ctor` body.

Thus you face penalty of having additional calls if you don't initialize in initialization list.

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 12.6.2/10 Initializing bases and members

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
>   following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8),
>   virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a
>   depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of
>   base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the
>   base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as
>   they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the
>   mem-initializers).
>
> — **Then, non-static data members are initialized** in the order they were
>   declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the
>   mem-initializers).
>
> — **Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed**.
>
> [ Note: The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and
>   member subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of
>   initialization. — end note ]

[Here is a code demo.](http://ideone.com/q043yr)

Comment: This is all fine, but I think that it doesn't answer the questions, and can introduce performance problems

Answer (score 3):

I would initialize the class `twoCats` like this:

```
class twoCats
{
private:
    cat firstCat;
    cat secondCat;
public:
    twoCats (const cat& theFirstCat, const cat& theSecondCat)
        : firstCat (theFirstCat), secondCat (theSecondCat)
    {
    }
};
```

The important part here is the colon after the constructor `:`. It starts the member initialization list, which is the place where, if possible, all your class data members should be initialized.

Initialization of data members is quite a complex issue in C++, I suggest you google it.

In particular, since you have two members of class type, the compiler, no matter what, tries to initialize them in your constructor. It does so for every cat, which probably is the reason you get the error message block twice. In its default, the compiler tries to initialize your cat data members using a default constructor, i.e. one without arguments. Unfortunately, `cat` does not have a default constructor, since you declared one with one argument. In other words, each cat has to be initialized with one argument (or copied, or moved in C++11).

I do not recommend declaring an additional constructor to `cat` without arguments: It seems that there is no "default hight" of a cat, and the `-1` suggested by another answer is very strange: It doesn't seem to construct a valid object, and you'd have to check for this default value before using any of `cat`'s member functions.

EDIT: This is from a format point of view. As for the semantics of your program, it might be wrong to copy the cats. Maybe you do need a reference (or a pointer) to the objects you initialized your twoCats with, maybe not.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful, I think for my actual problem (this cats program was just a MWE) I will use pointers to solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

Both cat instances have to be initialized, at the point when they start existing.

To avoid this you can defer each instance creation to when you need it.

A simple and safe way to do that is to use a `std::vector` to hold the instances.

```
class cat
{
    private:
        int height;
    public:
        cat (int inputHeight);
};

cat::cat (int inputHeight)
{
    height = inputHeight;
}

#include <vector>
#include <utility>

class twoCats
{
    private:
        std::vector<cat> cats_;

    public:
        twoCats (cat theFirstCat)
        { cats_.push_back( std::move( theFirstCat ) ); }

        void addSecondCat (cat theSecondCat)
        { cats_.push_back( std::move( theSecondCat ) ); }
};

int main() {return 0;}
```

---

Alternatively, you might use `boost::optional`.

Or allocate the instances dynamically (use a smart pointer such as `unique_ptr` to manage lifetime then).

Or, let cats be default-constructible.

---

As noted by "thang" in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076997/in-constructor-candidate-expects-1-argument-0-provided/26077075#comment40858860_26077075), the original design does not guarantee that a `twoCats` has two cats. It can have just one cat, or three or more cats. So it would be a good idea to **change the design**.

For example, have a constructor that takes two cat arguments, or cat heights.

Or for another example, changing the name of `twoCats`.

Comment: I think this is good except that you can accidentally add second cat many times.  In which case, twoCats is not two cats, which is a recipe for bugs later on.

Comment: @thang: true. i kept the design. if one starts changing the design it just becomes ... something *different*.

Comment: well I think if there is a constraint that it must be twoCats (2 cats), then the implementation either should not use vector (for example, 2 explicit smart pointers) or use vector and check for size.  On that note, addSecondCat should probably be setSecondCat.  The class name and (some of the) declaration calls for 1-2 association.

Comment: @thang: yeah, or change the name. but since there's no way to access the cats or even count them, any incorrect usage will probably go unnoticed. ;-)

Comment: Yes, it's "write only memory"...

Comment: Sorry guys, but this was just a MWE, there are obviously many design flaws in it, I should have probably said so in the question :P

Answer (score 0):

As name of your class (twoCats) states it represents two cats *always*. These kittens can be alive, dead or even not yet born. But it shall be two of them.

Your design is wrong in the sense that either:

- `cat` should be able to represent non-born cat (so it should have
  public default constructor setting the object into non-born state initially) or
- your twoCats constructor shall accept exactly two cats at the very beginning.

Comment: well, the design isn't wrong.  it depends on the requirements :p  It could be that the intention is to have a set of at most 2 cats and at least 1 cat.

Comment: The MWE I presented wasn't very well thought out, yes, for this example I really should have ensured the constructor could only ever accept two cats so there should always be two cat objects :)